# Ionic transition animation stuck/lag on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to develop web app. In the app, after logging in, it redirects to a page containing ion-slides, but the transition is not smooth, it will stuck with a part of former page(the logging in page) still in screen, when I click the screen(maybe focus??) , the transition can be completed and the latter page will be in the screen totally.

```
<ion-content scroll="false" class="myevents-content" ng-show="isCardViewer" ng-animate="'animate'">
    <ion-slides options="options" slider="$parent.slider" class="myevents-content-slider">
```

So is the problem related to the animation?? And any idea to solve it?
THX.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve transition animation is to use this plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions#0.6.5
```

https://github.com/shprink/ionic-native-transitions

Do not forget to add all the JS file after you install the plugin in yor index.html. It will work on on devices.